# Bash completion programming , '@' is always removed in completion string

Tags: linux, bash, gentoo

I'm doing a bash completion for Gentoo , which search for packages , sets ( portage 2.2 new feature ) , but i met a problem when i'm using the following command:

> emerge @pres

And i'm supposed to get @preserved-libs , but bash turns it into:

> emerge pres

First thought would be problem with my script called "emerge-finder.pl" , so i double checked , and this script gave the right output.

And next i checked bash script:

```
_portage_cmd () {
        COMPREPLY=( `~/scripts/emerge-finder.pl ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}` )

}
complete -F _portage_cmd em
```

And i put a "echo ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}" before COMPREPLY line , and there's no output of "@" character , wired.

How can i keep my "@" from stripping off by bash ?
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting or escaping it might help...

So quoting :

```
emerge '@pres'
```

Or escaping :

```
emerge \@pres
```

Comment: That works , i modified my script and stripped the '\' in front if matched , but i still don't understand why '@' is removed , thanks ;-P

Comment: Are you by any chance evalling the string in Perl?

Comment: use eval ? i didn't really get you , but so far my script can give correct output.